# Arrays & type-safety using optionals, best practices?

Tags: swift

I am attempting to understand the difference between declaring the following optional arrays.

Question 1) In the below example imagine the arrays were appended with a nil value, what would occur & which variable declarations would not crash?

Question 2)similarly imagine we swapped out the type String with type someObject. If the object failed to initialize correctly and returned nil, what would occur & which variable declarations would not crash?

I believe the answer for both 1,2) is var three & var four. 
I also think var one & var two can work if they are initialized () but I am not sure. 
I am fairly certain var five & var six will crash when attempting to append the array.

Question 3) Assuming that I went with option var one & var two & they were initialized as a empty array, can I add nil/empty objects/strings?

Question 4) Assuming that I went with option var three & var four, would it be advisable to use compactmap to filter out nil values?

Question 5) Assuming I went with option var five and var six, would it be advisable to check for nil/empty object/strings using nil coalescing or a guard statement to check for a value?

```
var one : Array<String?> //array containing optional strings
//is the same type as
var two : [String?] //array containing optional strings

var three : Array<String?>? //optional array containing optional strings
//is the same type as
var four : [String?]? //optional array containing optional strings

var five : Array<String>? //optional array containing strings
//is the same type as 
var six : [String]? //optional array containing strings
```

I inherited a codebase where I am receiving a json response and using the coddle protocol to create a object based on a struct model. I noticed that the variables were declared.

```
var seven : [someModel]?
```

The model is

```
struct someModel {

var a : String?

}
```

Question 6) Am I correct to assume that because all the properties/attributes of the struct are optionals, a object representing the struct can safely be appended to var seven even if someModel.a = optional(nil)?

Comment: `Array<T>` and `[T]` are exactly equivalent. So that cuts out half the variants

Comment: optional arrays are generally semantically vacuous and should be avoided unless you actually want to distinguish empty array from nil.

Answer (score 5):

First, none of these will crash. `nil` is not anything like Java's NULL (or C's NULL, and almost nothing like ObjC's nil). Accessing `nil` is completely safe. It's just a value, like every other value. `nil` is just a piece of syntactic sugar around `Optional.none`. They are exactly the same. Optionals are just enums:

```
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case some(Wrapped)
    case none
}
```

There is also syntactic sugar so that you can write `Array<T>` as `[T]`. These are exactly the same thing.

Similarly, you can write `Optional<T>` as `T?`. These, again, are exactly the same thing.

```
var one : Array<String?> //array containing optional strings
var two : [String?] //array containing optional strings
```

These are arrays of `Optional<String>`. Each element can be `.some(string)` or it can be `.none`.

```
var three : Array<String?>? //optional array containing optional strings
var four : [String?]? //optional array containing optional strings
```

As you say, these are optional arrays of optional strings. They can be `.none` or `.some(array)`. In that `array` is identical to one and two above.

```
var five : Array<String>? //optional array containing strings
var six : [String]? //optional array containing strings
```

As you say, this is an optional array of strings. So it can be `.none` or it can be `.some(array)` where `array` is an array of strings (not optional strings).

> Question 6) Am I correct to assume that because all the properties/attributes of the struct are optionals, a object representing the struct can safely be appended to var seven even if someModel.a = optional(nil)?

Yes, though it's not `optional(nil)`; that would be an `String??` rather than a `String?`. It's just `nil`.

The only place that optionals will crash due to being nil is if you evaluate them with a `!` at the end. The only reason this crashes is because it literally means "please crash the program if this is nil," so don't use `!` unless you mean that.

This isn't really a best-practices question, but since you titled it that way, a few points:

- Type names should always have a leading capital letter.
- As a rule, I discourage optional collections. That includes `Array?` and `String?`. You need to ask: how is "no value" different than "empty value." If they're the same (and they usually are), then you should just use empty values. So instead of `nil`, just use `""` and `[]`. Then all the optionals go away, and the code becomes much simpler.